# ERROR for INSERT #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql

I always get an error if I want to insert value in my tables..

SQL:

```
INSERT INTO `login`( `lo_password`, `lo_userName`, `lo_eMail`) VALUES ("sdsdf!D","Test!s1","test@test.com")
```

Error:

> 1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`splitthebilldb`.`login`, CONSTRAINT `login_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`lo_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`lo_id_login`))

---

[image: DB structure]

Comment: Do you have the same error trying to insert the ID manually ?

Comment: u_id and lo_id are auto-increment but yes if I insert it manually I get the same error

Comment: Is my answer helping you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your constraint is not in the right order :

```
CONSTRAINT login_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (lo_id) REFERENCES users (lo_id_login))
```

should be :

```
CONSTRAINT login_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (lo_id_login) REFERENCES users (lo_id))
```

And you've to add this constraint into `USERS` table.

Comment: first, gg bro!!

Comment: Call me Eric porcq

Comment: Excuse me Antoine, yes your answer was very helpful. 
I just starting to use phpmyadmin and before I created the relations with the designer. This way you have to select the PK from the parent table first and than the FK. I did the same by using the relation view but there you have to go into the child table to create the relation.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, did you run into another problem ?

Comment: No it's all fine, I just tried to explain how I run into this problem. LOL